# Particle animation for iOS

Tags: ios, core-animation, particle-system

I'm in need of particle animation in my `UIView`-based 2D game. At present I'm using an array of images for particle animations. This makes my app size increase, and sometimes leads to memory leaks. Is there is any way to make particle animations using Core Animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cocos2d (see http://cocos2d-iphone.org/) is a framework for developing 2d games for iPhone. The source code for many examples include some particle animation demo's.

Comment: your correct but this is a simple 2d game based on uiview thats why i use the array of images. can you say any some other way for particle animation in uikit.

Comment: Check out the WW DC 2010 demos on the Apple Dev website - there's a video called 'Session 424 - Core Animation in Practice, Part 1' that shows particle animation using Core Animation (water particles from a fire hydrant towards the end). The sample code for that should be available for download.

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice examples how to do this in the Apress book "Advanced iPhone programming".  I have no interest in the book (financially) - but they go into this pretty well.  You can get a used copy for $20 or so.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Particle Designer (http://particledesigner.71squared.com/) which has a nice Objective-C sample application if you want to use their PEX files stand-alone OR you can export PLIST files that work in combination with the COCOOS2D framework (http://www.cocos2d.org/).