# Particle effects in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, core-graphics, particle-system

I've hired a developer to work on an iPhone & iPad application and as part of the application we would like to have a particle effect.

How do you implement particle effects by using CoreGraphics?
Please note that I've referred the developer to the following link, but he's told me it doesn't work well due to leaks:
http://www.clingmarks.com/generate-particles-along-a-path/822

Comment: possible duplicate of [particle animation in iphone sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555161/particle-animation-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

If I may suggest this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial tutorial in an attempt to implement your particles, maybe you will have some better luck with it. I havent personally used it, but I've used tons of other tutorials from Ray's site, and all of them are fantastic.

Additionally, if you just want to debug your current implementation, this one seems to be up your alley: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial.

Hope that helps!